# How to declare not a known variable in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm getting error for max_split := len; line

```
 if max_split < 0 then
    max_split := len;
  else
    max_split := least(max_split, len);
  end if;
```

like *max_split" is not a known variable*
But i have declared this variable as

```
max_split integer DEFAULT '-1'::integer
```

Comment: please show an [mcve]

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and show us the complete code of your stored function or procedure

Comment: Unrelated, but: `'-1'::integer` can be simplified to `-1`